# AssertionError: The model ir.actions.url does not exist

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm going to add menu item when click on that which is navigate user to google.com.
i tried with code in forums but its not worked and gives above error.

please advice me to implement this issue & tell me if there another way to do this

```
    <record model="ir.actions.url" id="google_url">
        <field name="name">Google URL</field>
        <field name="url">http://www.google.com</field>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="google_url" name="Go google" parent="menu_bpl_logic"
        action="bpl_allowance_individual_data_action" sequence="" />
```

(if we need to open web page within exist openerp page & inside a frame, then how above code need to change ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ir.actions.act_url` instead of `ir.actions.url`